# AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application error

Tags: python, flask, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

i try to use the Quickstart sign-in of Microsoft using python.

Currently i have this in redirects URL: [redirect url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGh80.png)

and in my config file i have: [Config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1ipq.png)

i have not make any change in the others files but when i try to test i receive this message:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVKpo.png)

how can i solve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when the real redirect_uri doesn't match the reply url in Azure portal. You can track the auth request url to find the real redirect_uri. The request url is something like

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize? client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e &response_type=code &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12345 &response_mode=query &resource=https%3A%2F%2Fservice.contoso.com%2F &state=12345
```

After clicking sign in button and before inputting the account, you will find the request url.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reply URL in the portal needs to match exactly what is configured in the application code. For example, https and http register differently, and a mismatch would cause this error. The application ID/Client ID and tenant IDs also need to match in both places.You need to change the port from 5000 to the effective one.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. I was using the link from flask to go to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` instead of getting `http://localhost:5000/` in the  browser. Although both these urls point to the site, only the the localhost url is recognized by the app registration.